# Why we need to use angular cli?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

Hello everyone I want to learn angular, but I am bit confused like what is the use of angular cli??
Why I need to write 3 different files like `app.html`, `app.component.ts` and `app.module.ts` instead of writing code in those three files can't we use angular cdn directly? How better that component based architecture will work?

Please do not laugh at me I am new to this topic so previous are random questions that came to my mind while surfing the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI stands for Angular Command Line Interface ([see this link](https://angular.io/cli)). As the name implies, it is a command line tool for creating angular apps. It is recommended to use angular cli for creating angular apps as you don't need to spend time installing and configuring all the required dependencies and wiring everything together.

The Angular CLI is used for much more than just creating an Angular project. It can be used to create components, services, pipes, directives and more. Also it helps in building, serving, testing etc. CLI itself is quite something to learn about, it makes Angular development workflow much easier and faster.

Comment: But we never needed any CLI earlier. Every tool was available in Visual Studio.  Then why now we need CLI?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg go thru this link https://www.amadousall.com/why-you-should-use-angular-cli/ . Doing manually is very difficult compare to using commandLine

Comment: My question was when we already have visual studio 2017 (Free/ Licensed), why we are using CLI. Visual studio 2017 has the project template to quick start angular development in .Net. [Link Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: It's a task runner. You don't NEED to use it, but you can use it to make your life easier by automating common tasks. Since it's a command line tool, it can be used easily as part of a development pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide little more thorough answer on this and give a few examples too.

First of all, Angular CLI is a command-line interface tool that you use to initialize, develop, scaffold, and maintain Angular applications directly from a command shell. It saves you from the hassle of complex configurations and build tools like TypeScript, Webpack, and so on.

After installing Angular CLI, you’ll need to run one command to generate a project and another to serve it using a local development server to play with your application.

Here are a few basic and useful commands that show the benefit of using it:

```
ng help
ng generate --help
ng new my-first-project
cd my-first-project
ng serve
```

For more commands info and their full explanation refer to the official documentation here: [Angular CLI Official Page.](https://angular.io/cli)

You do not have to use Angular CLI in order to create and run and develop Angular apps, but isn't it best to use "GG" electric socket covers with "GG" frames for those covers?

Answer (score -1):

Angular cli can ease you work setting up maintain and customize your angular projects. Here are some of the main reasons you should use it:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects